# Unraveling the various types of [wiring]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[wiring](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wiring) is an undefined tag that enjoys varied usage:

- computer circuitry
- network connections
- home electrical wiring (power/grounding)
- phone line wiring/connection
- networking over electrical or phone wiring
- device cables
- wire types/usage

Almost all of the usages have existing specific tags or relate to devices/components that have specific tags.  The only exception is that there aren't tags for phoneline wiring/connection or phoneline networking.  It might be worth adding a catchall [phoneline](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/phoneline) tag.  Otherwise, I recommend deleting the [wiring] tag and retagging the questions with appropriate specific tags.

Comment: Oof, I started looking into all our wiring/cabling tags, and fell down a huge rabbit-hole :/ I'll write a full answer tomorrow hopefully, but from what I'm seeing we should have tags for [network-cabling], [computer-cabling] and probably a few others, and then merge stuff like [cat5], cat6] etc into those. Also: we have [tag:powerline-networking] for your fifth dot point :)

Comment: You didn't add an amusing title :( . Title suggestion ---> unraveling the various types of [wiring]

Comment: @allquixotic - You've got competition.